# split percussion staff in midi files in python

Tags: python, midi

I want to extract the acoustic bass drum part in midi files and output it(acoustic bass drum.mid) in python. For examples, I have a lot of midi files, then I want to extract acoustic bass drum part in them and output it in programming.(in one time, which means, batch splitting)

Currently I only can import one midi file into MuseScore software and split the percussion staff, then export it. But I don't want to do it one by one, I want to do it in programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**[`music21`](http://web.mit.edu/music21/)** is what you are looking for, go check it out.

Comment: Actually, I checked it, but don't know how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: check this out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/music21list/kWzojv7HZao/-wQ0ScqZeK4J, similar problem and a solution

Comment: This one is splitting midi file into sub midi files whose length is less, but what I want is to separate the percussion staff to extract the acoustic bass drum part to output it, which means the length of input midi file is the same as the output midi file. The difference is that input midi file consists of many staffs(piano, percussion, etc.), but the output midi file only consists of acoustic bass drum.

Comment: Well personally I've never really done that before, upon a quick look what I have in mind is read and parse the track with `music21.midi`, then extract what you want with `music21.instrument`, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually, I did this, but got nothing 

`from music21 import converter,instrument`
`s = converter.parse("C:\Users\PeterChen\Desktop\Taylor Swift - You Belong With Me.mid")`

`for el in s.recurse():
    if 'Percussion' in el.classes:
        print el`

Comment: `converter` does not parse raw mid file, you have to use `music21.midi.MidiFile`(http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleMidi.html#music21.midi.MidiFile) to read and parse the file first

Comment: sorry, I couldn't find the example of parsing the mid file, can you give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleMidiTranslate.html#music21.midi.translate.midiFileToStream

Comment: I used `for p in partStream:
 print p.partName` then the output is Saxophone
None
Electric Bass
None
None
Electric Guitar
None
None
None
Banjo
Banjo
Banjo
StringInstrument
Piano, I don't know which "None" is Percussion.

Comment: I guess when `music21` cannot recognize Percussion, you have to output them all and find out which one it is